# Parse perl array

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I'm not familiar with perl and am trying to edit an irssi translation script. The result from a web request returns as:

```
$result = {
 "data" => {
  "translations" => [
   {
    "translatedText" => "Halloween"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

How can I fetch only the translatedText portion, so that

```
$string = 'Halloween'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

"Halloween" could be obtained as:

```
$result->{"data"}->{"translations"}->[0]->{"translatedText"}
```

The arrows after the first one can be omitted, so an even shorter variant would be:

```
$result->{"data"}{"translations"}[0]{"translatedText"}
```

Basically you have multiple indirections at different levels:

- reference to a hash
- its "data" key being a reference to another hash
- the "translations" key of the last hash being a reference to an array
- the first element of that array is a reference to a hash
- the "translatedText" key of that hash is a string

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
$result->{data}->{translations}->[0]->{translatedText};
```

`$result` is a hash ref. The key 'data' points at yet another hash ref, which has a key 'translations' pointing at an array ref. The first and only element in that array ref has a key 'translatedText' which points at the data of interest: 'Halloween'.