# Parsing simple JSON array in Perl

Tags: json, perl, perl-data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse perl array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269236/parse-perl-array)

I'm trying to edit an old perl script and I'm a complete beginner.
The request from the server returns as:

```
$result = {
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Halloween"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

How can I parse this JSON string to grab:

```
$result = "Halloween"
```

Thanks.

Comment: No choice -- editing an existing irssi script

Comment: Please don't repost questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use JSON;

my $json = '{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "Halloween"
   }
  ]
 }
}';

my $data = decode_json($json);

say $data->{data}{translations}[0]{translatedText};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are uncountable JSON parsing modules available; the most standard-like one is [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm).

Answer (score 0):

You could take the easy way and do it like this (didn't check if this compiles):

```
my $translatedText = ""
if ($result =~ /"translatedText": "(.+?)"/)
{
    $translatedText = $1;
}
```

if you want to parse for more items and different json strings then you should use some perl module (there are a few avaialble)

Comment: Clever. This would be great, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I checked the regex here: http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php and it works...what error do you get?